# Remove close (X) button from the top right corner and keep min/max on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to create my UI with a JFrame and a minimize and maximize look-alike button with the same functionality as normal minimize and maximize buttons but I am not sure how. I want to take this approach so there will not be an X button in the top corner.

Comment: As a user, this would make me cringe.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** remove it and keep the other two, however, you can disable it using [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29):

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
```

Note that this will not make the button *unclickable* but will disable the functionality.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that disable the *functionality* while still giving the button a clickable appearance?

Comment: @tieTYT That's right. I don't think there's a way to disable the "clickability".

Comment: The question was to create your own Jpanel and add 'look-a-like' buttons that have the min/max functionality.

Comment: I need to keep min/max only so DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE option won't help

Answer (score 1):

For an undecorated frame you'd have to use [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) instead of JFrame, then render your own title bar.

Of course, whatever you render will only look right on one particular platform in one particular look and feel (unless you write your own logic to handle different platform conventions by hand). For example, Mac users will expect the close, min and max buttons to be traffic light coloured circles at the *left* hand end of the title bar, not square buttons at the right.